# Can applications push themselves in Windows?

Tags: windows, security, usb-flash-drive, webcam

Can application/programs be pushed in Windows?

I have a web-cam(Life-Cam HD) which has a button on it to open an application.So from what i understand, it triggers a script which opens the desired application(Windows telephone)

[image]

**Is *this* a way of pushing application to Windows?**

Can't I make a flashdrive/pendrive to with such a button to run an application? s this a security risk?

Comment: So your question is actually “Can a device install an application without me knowing it?” and the answer is no. I very much doubt this button is anything but a regular media button.

Comment: This button probably hooks into some default Windows behavior, or has its own driver that supports the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That button is simply a button.  Pushing it simply creates an electrical connection.  There is no program stored in the web cam, so nothing is being "pushed" to the OS.

The button's state will be controlled/monitored by a [device driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver) for the OS, made by the device's creators.  When the device driver detects the button is pushed, the driver will perform an action (run a script, for example).

> Can't I make a flashdrive/pendrive to with such a button to run an application?

If you did, you'd have to create a device driver for the OSs that you wanted the button to work with, as the standard USB storage protocols don't supply methods for handling buttons.

Comment: The camera could have flash storage, with the program installed, but pressing the button wouldn't install the program if it wasn't installed.  With the internet age hardware, that has flash storage for that purpose, is sort of pointless, sort of like drivers being included with it, easier to include a $.000000000000001 piece of paper with a web address :-)

Comment: There is a standard for (sort-of) arbitrary buttons: HID. I’m pretty sure this button is the same as the “answer phone” button on my headset.

Comment: @DanielB No different then a keyboard that has media buttons, the camera likely is being reported has both a camera and a keyboard to Windows

Comment: @DanielB Good point about standard HID drivers, so he could perhaps avoid writing the device drive if he just wanted a "button". I'm have no actual idea, but I doubt the standard HID drivers would include methods for dumping and running a program from the device though (security reasons? :) )

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 No, they don’t. It’s really (almost) exclusively for input, though you can also facilitate “driverless” communication with devices.