# Does a USB password key push the password?

Tags: usb, passwords, arduino

I recently asked a question
[Can applications push themselves in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1144351/can-applications-push-themselves-in-windows)

where an appealing answer wrote that

> Pushing it simply creates an electrical connection. There is no
>   program stored in the web cam, so nothing is being "pushed" to the OS.

In a USB key there are no buttons. So my question/s is/are

**1. Does a USB password key push the password to the operating system?**

**2. How does the USB password store the key?**

I recently came across the ATtiny85 which can be used for the purpose of the key.

**Is this device capable of pushing data/commands/passwords to the OS?**

Answer (score 1):

It pretends to be a HID and keys in the password emulating a keyboard.

In fact, there's boards based on microcontrollers that can emulate or act as a controller for a keyboard - most famously the [teensy](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/), and similar devices uses for [good](http://codeandlife.com/2012/03/03/diy-usb-password-generator/) and [evil](https://hakshop.com/products/usb-rubber-ducky-deluxe).

Since every modern PC uses a standard USB keyboard, no additional drivers are needed.

Comment: Can a USB key store many password? if yes how  does it know which pwd?

Comment: In theory, yes, but you'd need some form of input/output for that. Something like the mooltipass, while not a simple key would work. *or* the key stores a key which is used to verify your identity, like with U2F